# MariaDB Galera replication under Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, mariadb, galera, xtrabackup

I'm provisioning a Galera MySQL cluster under Vagrant using a multi machine VagrantFile.

I don't believe the issue lies with Vagrant

#### Vagrant Version

[image: Vagrant Version 1.8.6]

#### VagrantFile

```ruby
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.memory = "2048"
  end

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-cachier")
    config.cache.scope = :box
    config.cache.enable :apt
  end

  config.vm.define "core0" do |core0|
      core0.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.3"
      core0.vm.hostname = "core0"
      core0.vm.provision :hosts, :sync_hosts => true
      core0.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
          sudo python /vagrant/bootstrap.pex --core-nodes core0 core1 core2 --node-zero
      SHELL
  end

  config.vm.define "core1" do |core1|
      core1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
      core1.vm.hostname = "core1"
      core1.vm.provision :hosts, :sync_hosts => true
      core1.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
          sudo python /vagrant/bootstrap.pex --master core0 --core
      SHELL
  end

  config.vm.define "core2" do |core2|
      core2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.5"
      core2.vm.hostname = "core2"
      core2.vm.provision :hosts, :sync_hosts => true
      core2.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
          sudo python /vagrant/bootstrap.pex --master core0 --core
      SHELL
  end

end
```

#### Vagrant Plugins

I'm using the `vagrant-cachier` and `vagrant-hosts` in vagrant. 
Vagrant runs and creates each VM in turn and then I do a 2 stage provision to ensure the networking between the boxes is established before attempting clustering.

```bash
vagrant up --provision-with hosts && vagrant provision --provision-with shell
```

the shell provisioner uses salt to creates and installs mariadb and gluster

#### Mariadb versions

```
vagrant@core0:~$ sudo apt-cache policy mariadb-server-core-10.1 
mariadb-server-core-10.1:
  Installed: 10.1.18+maria-1~trusty
  Candidate: 10.1.18+maria-1~trusty

vagrant@core0:~$ sudo apt-cache policy galera-3       
    galera-3:
      Installed: 25.3.18-trusty
      Candidate: 25.3.18-trusty
```

I configure the galera.cnf with the cluster addresses as

`wsrep_cluster_address = gcomm://core2,core0,core1`

when hosts `core1` and `core2` attempt to join with `core0` they are unable to.

#### core1 joining cluster

core1 is able to find the core0 and retrieve the current cluster state.

```
Oct 12 15:15:02 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:02 140403237877696 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'TestSystem', peer 'core2:,core0:,core1:'
Oct 12 15:15:02 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:02 140403237877696 [Note] WSREP: (a61950db, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection established to a61950db tcp://127.0.0.1:4567
Oct 12 15:15:02 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:02 140403237877696 [Note] WSREP: (a61950db, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection established to a61950db tcp://127.0.1.1:4567
Oct 12 15:15:02 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:02 140403237877696 [Warning] WSREP: (a61950db, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') address 'tcp://127.0.1.1:4567' points to own listening address, blacklisting
Oct 12 15:15:02 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:02 140403237877696 [Note] WSREP: (a61950db, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection established to a5301480 tcp://192.168.50.3:4567
Oct 12 15:15:02 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:02 140403237877696 [Note] WSREP: (a61950db, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting on, nonlive peers: 
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:03 140403237877696 [Note] WSREP: declaring a5301480 at tcp://192.168.50.3:4567 stable
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:03 140403237877696 [Note] WSREP: Node a5301480 state prim
```

#### core2 not available

as expected at this time core2 is not available

```
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:03 140403237877696 [Note] WSREP: discarding pending addr without UUID: tcp://192.168.50.5:4567
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:03 140403237877696 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
```

#### SST failure

core1 attempts to connect to core0 using the address `10.0.2.15` which is the Vagrant NAT address

```
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:03 140403237563136 [Note] WSREP: State transfer required: 
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 mysqld: #011Group state: a530f9fd-908d-11e6-a72a-b2e3a6b91029:1113
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 mysqld: #011Local state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:03 140403237563136 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: a530f9fd-908d-11e6-a72a-b2e3a6b91029:1113, view# 2: Primary, number of nodes: 2, my index: 1, protocol version 3
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:03 140403237563136 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:03 140402002753280 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'joiner' --address '10.0.2.15' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/'   --parent '9043' --binlog '/var/log/mariadb_bin/mariadb-bin' '
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 mysqld: WSREP_SST: [INFO] Logging all stderr of SST/Innobackupex to syslog (20161012 15:15:03.985)
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 -wsrep-sst-joiner: Streaming with xbstream
Oct 12 15:15:03 core1 -wsrep-sst-joiner: Using socat as streamer
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 -wsrep-sst-joiner: Evaluating timeout -k 110 100 socat -u TCP-LISTEN:4444,reuseaddr stdio | xbstream -x; RC=( ${PIPESTATUS[@]} )
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:04 140403237563136 [Note] WSREP: Prepared SST request: xtrabackup-v2|10.0.2.15:4444/xtrabackup_sst//1
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:04 140403237563136 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 7 (3, 2)
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:04 140402075592448 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:04 140403237563136 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 1113, protocol version: 3
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:04 140402075592448 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:04 140403237563136 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (a530f9fd-908d-11e6-a72a-b2e3a6b91029): 1 (Operation not permitted)
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 mysqld: #011 at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():482. IST will be unavailable.
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:04 140402019526400 [Note] WSREP: Member 1.0 (core1) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 0.0 (core0)(SYNCED) as donor.
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:04 140402019526400 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 1113)
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:04 140403237563136 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 0
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:04 140402019526400 [Warning] WSREP: 0.0 (core0): State transfer to 1.0 (core1) failed: -32 (Broken pipe)
Oct 12 15:15:04 core1 mysqld: 2016-10-12 15:15:04 140402019526400 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_group.cpp:gcs_group_handle_join_msg():736: Will never receive state. Need to abort.
```

#### wsrep status on core0

logging into mysql on core0 and running

```sql
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_%'


+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
...
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | a530f9fd-908d-11e6-a72a-b2e3a6b91029 |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                              |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid             | a5301480-908d-11e6-a84e-0b2444c3985f |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | 10.0.2.15:3306                       |
| wsrep_local_state            | 4                                    |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Synced                               |
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | a530f9fd-908d-11e6-a72a-b2e3a6b91029 |
...
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

So it appears that core0 is advertising its wsrep incoming address as `10.0.2.15:3306`, which isn't the address I'm expecting -  `192.168.0.3:3306`.

### ifconfig on core0

this shows the NAT on eth0

```
vagrant@core0:~$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:de:04:89  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fede:489/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:218886 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:81596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:205966097 (205.9 MB)  TX bytes:6015101 (6.0 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:bc:f7:ee  
          inet addr:192.168.50.3  Bcast:192.168.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:febc:f7ee/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:261637 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:244284 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:59467905 (59.4 MB)  TX bytes:114065906 (114.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:246320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:246320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:64552545 (64.5 MB)  TX bytes:64552545 (64.5 MB)
```

How / Why does the address get set to this? Is there a way I can make the address the correct address?

### updates

#### how wsrep_incoming_addresses is set

> While wsrep_cluster_address has to be specified at the node start,
>   wsrep_incoming_addresses is internally determined during the
>   initialization. On linux operation systems, the command that is used
>   to determine the IP address picks the first available global IP
>   address from the list of interfaces.

```bash
ip addr show | grep '^\s*inet' | grep -m1 global | awk '
{print $2 }
' | sed 's/\/.*//'
```

https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-5487

my output

```bash
vagrant@core0:~$ ip addr show | grep '^\s*inet' | grep -m1 global | awk '
> {print $2 }
> ' | sed 's/\/.*//'
10.0.2.15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to set the `wsrep_sst_receive_address` setting

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/galera-cluster-system-variables/#wsrep_sst_receive_address

Setting this to be the hostname that I had assigned to the Vagrant box solved this for me